# Windows 11 stuck on startup.nsh (Mac M1 Monterey 12.6.6 (21G646))

Tags: mac, virtual-machine, window, arm

I've download UTM and Fusion.
I have tried on multiple versions of UTM to boot up the Windows 11 ARM 64, however I am always stuck on startup.nsh.
I have followed several tutorials on how to install.
Whenever I create the new VM after booting the Windows11 ISO files, the VM just held at this screen. Please if anyone can help that would be great.

I tried Fusion, but it is the same problem.
The ISO i have tried:

22621.1702.230505-1222.ni_release_svc_refresh_CLIENTCONSUMER_RET_A64FRE_en-gb

22621.1702.230505-1222.ni_release_svc_refresh_CLIENTCONSUMER_RET_A64FRE_en-us

25926.1000.230804-1441.RS_PRERELEASE_CLIENTMULTI_A64FRE_EN-US

[image]